# Testing a @KafkaListener using Spring Embedded Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-boot-test

I am trying to write a unit test for a Kafka listener that I am developing using Spring Boot 2.x. Being a unit test, I don't want to start up a full Kafka server an instance of Zookeeper. So, I decided to use Spring Embedded Kafka.

The definition of my listener is very basic.

```
@Component
public class Listener {
    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    @Autowired
    public Listener(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "sample-topic")
    public void listen(String message) {
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Also the test, that verifies the `latch` counter to be equal to zero after receiving a message, is very easy.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = { "sample-topic" })
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}" })
public class ListenerTest {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka;

    @Autowired
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> producer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.producer = buildKafkaTemplate();
        this.producer.setDefaultTopic("sample-topic");
    }

    private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> buildKafkaTemplate() {
        Map<String, Object> senderProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka);
        ProducerFactory<Integer, String> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(senderProps);
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }

    @Test
    public void listenerShouldConsumeMessages() throws InterruptedException {
        // Given
        producer.sendDefault(1, "Hello world");
        // Then
        assertThat(latch.await(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the test fails and I cannot understand why. Is it possible to use an instance of `KafkaEmbedded` to test a method marked with the annotation `@KafkaListener`?

All the code is shared in my GitHub repository [kafka-listener](https://github.com/rcardin/kafka-listener).

Thanks to all.

Comment: See the edit to my answer; I didn't notice you weren't using boot's config properties for the consumer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are probably sending the message before the consumer has been assigned the topic/partition. Set property...

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
```

...it defaults to `latest`.

This is like using `--from-beginning` with the console consumer.

**EDIT**

Oh; you're not using boot's properties.

Add

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

**EDIT2**

BTW, you should probably also do a `get(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` on the result of the `template.send()` (a `Future<>`) to assert that the send was successful.

**EDIT3**

To override the offset reset just for the test, you can do the same as what you did for the broker addresses:

```
@Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset:latest}")
private String reset;

...

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, this.reset);
```

and

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}",
        "spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest"})
```

However, bear in mind that this property only applies the first time a group consumes. To always start at the end each time the app starts, you have to seek to the end during startup.

Also, I would recommend setting `enable.auto.commit` to `false` so that the container takes care of committing the offsets rather than just relying on the consumer client doing it on a time schedule.

Comment: Thank you. Set the `auto.offset.reset` property to `earliest` made the magic :)

Comment: However, if I need to use `latest` as `auto.offset.reset` value? How can I make the test works? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is this ever testing the "Listener" class that contains the @KafkaListener method? I see the CountDownLatch assertion, but never any assertion that the method was hit...

Comment: ? the code in the `@KafkaListener` method counts down the latch, hence it was called.Typically, however, you wouldn't do it like this. Most likely the listener invokes a service and you would inject a mock or stubbed service instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will find this useful. I had a similar problem.
Locally tests were running (some checks were performed within `Awaitility.waitAtMost`) but in the Jenkins pipeline, tests were failing.

The solution was, like already mentioned in the most voted answer, setting `auto-offset-reset=earliest`.
When tests are running, you can check if you set the configuration properly by looking into test logs. Spring outputs configuration for both producer and consumer

Comment: Very useful, thanks! When I was using Intellij I had the same problem trying to collect Coverage.